# Table has duplicate data and can't get two aggregates functions to work in SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

The problem is that the table "addresses" has multiple entries where a user has updated their address. I just need the latest one. I tried to use `MAX(uPDATED_AT)` in the "addresses" table but get an error. Well, I first wrote the code below and realized many rows are duplicates or close to duplicates. I just need to grab their *last* change to their address but I get errors when trying to add another aggregate to the `HAVING` clause. Can someone please assist? I am a newbie at SQL but would love to know the issue and correct it going forward.

I am using PostgreSQL by the way

```
Select
  last_name,
  first_name,
  donator,
  customer_id,
  phone, 
  address,
  city,
  state,
  zipcode,
  events.buyer_id

  from events 

  join addresses on events.buyer_id = addresses.buyer_id 
  inner join customer_extras on addresses.buyer_id = customer_extras.buyer_id
  inner join Customer_roles on events.buyer_id = Customer_roles.buyer_id
  inner join People on Customer_roles.buyer_id = People.id

  group by 
  customer_id,
  member_status,
  events.event_type,
  first_name,
  last_name,
  address,
  city,
  state,
  phone,
  donator,
  zipcode,
  events.buyer_id

  HAVING MIN(events.created_at) between '2015-06-01'
  and '2015-08-01' and event_type ILIKE 'MEMBER_TABLET%' and member_status IN 
  ('moved','never answered', 'refused', 'complete')
```

Comment: use dense_rank function

Comment: where would i use that?  And thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use windowing functions, your query will look like this

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by <column_with_duplicate_values> order by <date> desc) dr from ...
```

Above query gives ranks in descending order. You need to enclose in another query

```
select * from (<above_query>) q where dr=1;
```

Comment: I can't seem to get your ranking code to work. Can you assist? I need to know where my query would fit in or how it would. I get errors when running my code in your code here section.  Please , your help is much appreciated.  I took work home with me as I really want to get this working asap.

Comment: Here is the tested query and modified for you.  "select * from (
select * from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by userid order by date desc) dr from addresses t) q  where q.dr = 1) q1
join ...;" You need to modify by adding the tables after join clause

Comment: I have a couple questions regarding your response. i am new to sql and am not familiar with t.*  .  What does this mean?  I am aware of *.  but not t.*

Comment: t is alias for the query in the from clause "select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by <column_with_duplicate_values> order by <date> desc) dr from <table> t;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `addresses` table has a field named `create_date` (I'm guessing, but you can sub your actual field name), I think you want to use my favorite analytic function, row_number:

```
with most_recent_address as (
  select a.*, row_number() over (partition by buyer_id order by create_date desc) as rn
  from addresses as a  -- fix is here
)
Select 
  last_name, first_name, donator, customer_id,
  phone, address, city, state, zipcode,
  events.buyer_id
from events 
  join most_recent_address a on events.buyer_id = a.buyer_id and a.rn = 1
  inner join customer_extras on addresses.buyer_id = customer_extras.buyer_id
  inner join Customer_roles on events.buyer_id = Customer_roles.buyer_id
  inner join People on Customer_roles.buyer_id = People.id
where
  event_type ILIKE 'MEMBER_TABLET%' and 
  member_status IN ('moved','never answered', 'refused', 'complete')
group by 
  customer_id, member_status, events.event_type,
  first_name, last_name, address, city,
  state, phone, donator, zipcode, events.buyer_id
HAVING
  MIN(events.created_at) between '2015-06-01' and '2015-08-01'
```

Again, if the ranking mechanism is not create_date, change it to whatever it should be.

Depending on the size of your data, you may want to switch to the `max` analytic.  It does not invoke an `order by` and therefore should be O(n).  However, note that if you have two of the same create_date values for the same buyer_id, this will yield two records instead of one.  You know your data better than I do, so you can probably assess the risk of this vs the improved performance:

```
with most_recent_address as (
  select a.*, max(create_date) over (partition by buyer_id) as max_date
  from addresses as a
)
Select 
  last_name, first_name, donator, customer_id,
  phone, address, city, state, zipcode,
  events.buyer_id
from events 
  join most_recent_address a on events.buyer_id = a.buyer_id and a.create_date = a.max_date
  inner join customer_extras on addresses.buyer_id = customer_extras.buyer_id
  inner join Customer_roles on events.buyer_id = Customer_roles.buyer_id
  inner join People on Customer_roles.buyer_id = People.id
where
  event_type ILIKE 'MEMBER_TABLET%' and 
  member_status IN ('moved','never answered', 'refused', 'complete')
group by 
  customer_id, member_status, events.event_type,
  first_name, last_name, address, city,
  state, phone, donator, zipcode, events.buyer_id
HAVING
  MIN(events.created_at) between '2015-06-01' and '2015-08-01'
```

Also, and you didn't ask this, but you may notice I moved two of your conditions from the `having` to the `where` clause.  This should help improve query performance, as you are eliminating rows BEFORE the grouping rather than after.  `Having` is only necessary (over `where`) when you apply the condition to a grouping function.  Since ordering/grouping is among the most expensive operations on the database, this can make a big difference with large datasets.

Comment: If it doesn't work, post the DDL for your tables.  Your endeavor sounds do-able.

Comment: getting this error on yours ? 
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"

LINE 2:   select a.*, row_number() over (partition by person_id orde...

Comment: Ok I will post some ddl.  I just see a.* is giving trouble. I am not sure what a.* actually means . I see the a.* alot and never have I used it.  Is it the same as *.  I suppose it's not but just wondering.

Comment: My bad...  I forgot to alias "addresses" as a.  Fixing it now.

Comment: Address  People  Events  Customer_Roles  Customer_Extras 
Buyer_id pk First_Name string created_at datetime donator string home_phone string
Address1 string Last_Name string event_type string Customer_id string Buyer_id unique id
Address2 string Buyer_id unique id Buyer_id unique id Buyer_id unique id  
city string        
state string        
zipcode string        
Updated_At datetime

Comment: tried to add my ddl in here but its pretty messed up on formatting

Comment: I tried to add an alias for addresses and it didnt work

Comment: Hey sorry...  had to get some shut-eye.  Can you edit your original post with the DDL for each of the tables?  Just put them at the end of your question (that way it will be formatted, easy to read, no limitations on how much you can paste).  Or, you can open a SQLFiddle and set up your tables there with sample data and all, but I think the DDL will be sufficient.  It's got to be something simple -- I am hopefuly my query is 95% there, I'm just missing something specific to your tables.